# Using ngModel with Reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In my application I was using template driven validation but now I have to switch to Model driven approach but I did not want to remove two way data binding.So my html controls were like that

```
form [formGroup]="myForm">
    input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selected.HasFull" formControlName="HasFull" /
```

But it started to throw this error

> ```
>   ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
>   formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:
> ```

```
div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  input formControlName="firstName"
/div

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});

  Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:

  Example:


div [formGroup]="myGroup">
   input formControlName="firstName">
   input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
</div
```

Then I added this [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" to my html controls but it gave me the error [ngModelOptions] is not a known property of input.

> **Update**
>   the problem of not a known property of input went away when I replaced [ngModelOptions] with ng-model-options but I was still getting the error "ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive."
>   I had two fields on the form which did not require validation so they did not have formControlName attribute. As a work around I made those two fields part of my fromgroup and added the formControlName attribute on them and it is working fine now.Although I did not require validation for these two fields but at least I'm not getting an error.

Comment: Could you please show us how you build the form and the value of `selected` which you use in your ngModel, and perhaps how your complete form looks like.